# How to retrieve Yahoo search auto suggestions through selenium and xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

The following code is generating error in Xpath. The xpath is for dynamic element and I used start-with. I do not get any error before I run the code, but after I run it, eclipse is generating error. Please help:

```
package com.TSOne.tcone;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class YahooTextSearch {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/owner/desktop/chromedriver");
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
         driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-box")).sendKeys("selen");
         List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'yui_3_18_0_3_1528696’)]"));
         System.out.println(list.size());
       }
}
```

Comment: it's never a good idea to use dynamic id in selenium. after sending "selen" what do you want to do ?Which element locates  //*[starts- 
with(@id,'yui_3_18_0_3_1528696’)]  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey: The list of elements is retrieved by using the locator "//*[starts- 
with(@id,'yui_3_18_0_3_1528')]".

Comment: @Monika : we don't know the intention of OP after just sending the selen string to search box. He might wanna click on search button and then want to retrieve a list of web element.

Comment: @Monica:Thank you.

Comment: @cruisepandey:Thank you

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, change

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'yui_3_18_0_3_1528696’)]
                                         ^
```

to

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'yui_3_18_0_3_1528696')]
                                         ^
```

(Replace the marked curly single *quote* with a *straight* single quote.)

Follow-up with details if you have additional problems.  Note that `//*` is a costly operation in general in XPath, and particularly in Selenium 
[thanks for helpful comment, [@cruisepandey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9444073/cruisepandey)] – specifying an element name, if possible, would avoid potential performance issue.

Comment: It's an even worse idea to use syntactically incorrect XPath's anywhere, including with Selenium.  That's all this answer is meant to say.  If OP had further problems, I expected a follow-up from OP.

Comment: Agreed. Though you could have mentioned about that in your answer.

Comment: @cruisepandey: Answer updated per your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the size of the list generated after entering the text "Selen" in the search box then you should use the code mentioned below:

```
      driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
      driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-box")).sendKeys("selen");
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
      List<WebElement> list=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='yui3-aclist-content']//li[contains(@class,'aclist-item')]")));

      System.out.println(list.size());
```

Please note that you cannot use the locator "**//*[starts- 
with(@id,'yui_3_18_0_3_1528696')]**" because the numbers after **yui_3_18_0_3_1528** are changing on reloading the page.

Comment: Though your xpath is fine , But it's an assumption until OP clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the *Yahoo search* **auto suggestions** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#uh-search-box"))).sendKeys("selen");
  List<WebElement> yahoo_search_auto_suggestions = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("ul.yui3-aclist-list li>span")));
  for (WebElement suggestion:yahoo_search_auto_suggestions)
      System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  selena gomez
  selenium
  selena break up
  selena gomez pics
  selena gomez songs
  selenium ide
  selenium tutorial
  selena quintanilla
  seleniumhq.org
  selenium interview questions
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: Yahoo_auto_suggestion]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for doing so :

```
    WebDriver driver = PlayField.getChromeDriver();  
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.yahoo.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-box"));
    inputField.sendKeys("Bye");
    List<String> autoSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul[role='listbox'] li span span"))
                                         .stream()
                                         .map(suggestion -> suggestion.getAttribute("innerText"))
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(autoSuggestions);
```

If not using implicit wait than also you can wait for visibility of elements for selector "ul[role='listbox'] li span span" .

You can use this xpath also if you only want to do it using xpath: "//ul[@role='listbox']/li/span/span"

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    //setting gecko driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",paste path of the gecko driver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",paste path of the gecko driver");

    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    //launching yahoo 
    driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us");
    //Entering text in to the yahoo search text field
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='uh-search-box']")).sendKeys("selenium");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//ul[@class='yui3-aclist-list']/li/span/span"));

    //getting size of the search results from suggestion box
    System.out.println(ele.size());

    //getting text from the suggestion box
    for (WebElement e : ele) {
        System.out.println(e.getText());
    }
}
```

try this hope this will work